# Excel table default value and data validation without VBA

Tags: excel, validation

I have a table in Excel for tracking projects. Whenever I create a new row for the table I'd like it to auto-populate one column that the project has "Not Invoiced". I would ALSO like that this column use Data Validation to only allow either "Not Invoiced" or "Invoiced" as content.

I have been able to make both of these things work, but I cannot seem to make them work together without error! The closest I have gotten:

- Put a formula in the relevant column. Have tried both the super basic `="Not Invoiced"` as well as an `=IF` formula based on the blankness of another column. This correctly carries down each time I make a new row.
- I then add Data Validation on the column which also works fine at first since my default value from my formula is one of the options, HOWEVER when the project does invoice and I select "Invoiced" I then get an error that I'm violating the above formula. From what I've read selecting something from the drop down should just replace the auto-populated formula, but that doesn't seem to happen, it gives me an error that I've violating the column's formula instead.

I've read multiple places that if you correctly order things (create table, add formula for default value, then add data validation) the above method should work, but it will not for me and I continue to get the error every time I change to "Invoiced".

Answer (score 0):

you can enter the stati "Not Invoiced" and "Invoiced" into cells that are close together, e.g. $G$3 and $G$4. Then, create a named range for $G$3:$G$4, let's say "ValList" (menu: Formula / Define Name).

Imagine column A to be the controlling column, and B the status column ("Invoiced" / "Not Invoiced"). Example for cell B5:

The initial status is =IF(A5=""; ""; $G$3)

The Validation (type "List") must be controlled by a formula =IF(A5=""; " "; ValList)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do this.

Before you start using a new table, add list data validation to the cell in the first and only row:

```
Invoiced,Not Invoiced
```

Then, in the first row of your table in that same cell write:

```
=IF(TRUE,"Not Invoiced";"Not Invoiced")
```

This will put `Not Invoiced` as the default value on every new row that is added to the table and also keep data validation in place. You will still have access on every new row's cell to the dropdown list stored in the initial cell's data validation list parameter.

For some reason, data validation is overwritten if you try the same IF-function approach in reference to another cell, as you described it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to use a helper column.
You can use the data validation list for the entry column, say column A.
You can use a formula in the hidden column B with the formula =IF(A1,"Invoiced","Invoiced","Not invoiced")